# MVC5 HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, video-streaming

I have a video library developed using C# MVC5.  I import videos into my video library and try to display "stream" them when a user clicks on the video in the front end.

The video is being rendered using the HTML5 video tag, but according to what I have read, there needs to be separate video files for each of the different browsers.

What is the best way to achieve this?  The videos being imported are in MP4 format, which plays in Chrome but not in the other browsers.  I see some articles on using ffmpeg to create "versions" of the video.

Any advice?

Comment: I'd say read out the browser when they land on your page before clicking on a video, call a method that sets the source for the video depending on the browser (e.g. .MP4 for IE, .OGV for Firefox) and then load them in.

Comment: All browsers support MP4. Firefox was holding out for a while, but they do now as well.

Comment: MP4 with H.264 is [natively supported by all the main browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE). If it doesn't work, that could be because it is encoded in a "funky" way.

Comment: Right. @AlvaroMontoro is more correct here. MP4 is just the container. It really has to do with the encoding. H.264 is supported by all browsers. If your MP4 files are not working, then make sure they are encoded as H.264.

Comment: Thanks for the answers team.  I had the code inside one of my MVC views trying to stream a mp4 video.  The video was inside the actual site in a subfolder and the encoding was definitely correct according to your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answers team.  I had the code inside one of my MVC views trying to stream a mp4 video.  The video was inside the actual site in a subfolder and the encoding was definitely correct according to your comments.

tried all browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) and none worked.  Went back to basics and created a simple HTML page with the video tag.

Thoughts?  My video is 20mb so I doubt it is a download issue. my html looks like

`code`
<video id="viddy" controls="1" preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
<source src="/VIDS/Video123.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
`code`